# What can cause internet Lag Spikes while streaming League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, networking, streaming

Recently, I got kind of a lot lag spikes while using some internet programs at the same time. Now since I'd consider my connection speed as pretty good (10mbit up/100mbit down) and the problems are really just **spikes** and not a constant high ping, I wonder what causes this problem.

They usually only occur when I use the following programs at the same time:

- x-split broadcaster (streaming program, free version)
- Skype (not always in a conversation)
- Chrome with youtube/facebook
- League of Legends (Here I notice the spikes)

The spikes also don't necessarily occur when the next youtube video in the playlist is loaded. So could this be some kind of port issue? Or just the Riot servers (EUW is well known for its stable connection...)

When skyping I also usually don't get disconnected. Everything except LoL works pretty fine.

Comment: Usually streaming programs have a (configurable) constant uprate. I would consider trimming it down a bit, to check if the problem still persists. However, as you already mentioned, League of Legends EUW Server has very often lag-issues. This adds with the fact, that you get spikes instead of a constant higher ping. I think it should be easy to test, wether you have the same lag spikes with and without actually streaming. On another note, I would strongly recommend using Open Broadcaster Software isntead of XSplit. Afaik it's a bit mroe perfmromant. (Though it might not eliminate your problem)

Comment: Depending on your computer specs and network card, it is probably not a problem on your side. EU West used to be okay, but for the past year it has had a lot of connection issues. I normally get spikes every few minutes, but I get them more often when I'm in a steam groupchat. Have you tried turning of skype completely?

Comment: You can try playing any other online game. Also the best game to watch how your connection works between you and the server is ***Quake Live***: it has a graphic lagometer that shows you in **realtime** how and when your ping goes high: small, but is the one that I trust the most.

Comment: This is a screenshot I took about the lagometer, just write *cg_lagometer 2* in the game console http://prntscr.com/2p6i65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be happened to me too. It turns out I had a bad router, which cannot handle too much connection session.

Even though softwares like Skype don't take up a lot of bandwidth, it may require a lot of connection sessions.(I don't know how to explain, it's like passing a 1000g ball to a person, or passing 10 of 100g ball to 10 person.) If your router could not handle it, it may hang.

The first solution is to adjust the bitrate of streaming. How many bitrate did you use on your streaming? The suggested bitrate is 1800-2500Kb/s for 720p.

I would also like to suggest you to try the Open Broadcaster Software. It's a free, open source streaming software. I found it works better than Xsplit in my computer. It lags less, and video qualities are generally better(according to my friends/fans). It also provide 1080p streaming for free.

[OBS Official Site](https://obsproject.com/)

[OBS Setting Guide by Twitch](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1262922-open-broadcaster-software)

If the above solution doesn't work, then it is most likely about your router. Try to close unused software that would use up your network(like Panda Media or whatever, I don't know why the other answer get downvoted so much). Or, buy a better router.

My English could be painful to watch. But hopefully it solves your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Delete pando media booster if you still have it installed
http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1000329

Comment: Whats with the negative votes?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me a lot when I stream too.  I'm pretty sure it is my internet company.  The other programs have buffering but not league of legends (Except Skype).  What usually happens is I begin to disc in league of legends but still have some connection.  I can see see the enemies moving and sometimes I can still hear the skype conversation.

It could also be your router throttling.  When I was first streaming, my router thought something was trying to abuse my connection and so would disconnect me.

To be honest, it's most likely your internet provider.